Why do some people disagree about whether DTT implies not Turing complete?
The idea that being dependently typed as in Agda, Coq, etc., implies not being Turing complete, sometimes crops up (see below for a brief list, though which may be out of date), including on various StackExchange sites. Is part of the reason there is sometimes push-back on the idea that DTTs are not Turing complete that Turing completeness is itself often discussed in a messy/vague way?

Can the language of proof assistants be used for general purpose programming?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026006/is-there-a-version-of-turing-completeness-for-total-programming-languages
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295857/can-any-additional-axiom-make-coq-turing-complete)


https://stackoverflow.com/a/78535330

What is your exact question?

@MevenLennon-Bertrand why DTT seems to have become somehow associated with not being Turing complete (in many places outsiders such as myself stumble across).

My question is why is this such a contentious topic? I was genuinely surprised when someone accused me of spouting propaganda for saying that pure Lean wasn't Turing complete (your first link above). I felt in that particular case it was helpful as a pedagogical aid in my answer to explain the three types of languages in Lean. (Also, as a computability theorist by training, it was correct in that narrow interpretation.) Of course, you can program in any language with primitive recursion if you have the right interpretation. (A big enough for loop is a while loop in practice...)

The problem is that this is often implied to be some barrier to the programs that can be written in languages like Agda when that is just not the case. Like saying, "Haskell can't do I/O," because technically the I/O capabilities are an embedded language, not every expression. That is a misleading technicality unless further clarified. Similarly, the fact that, say, $ℕ → ℕ$ in Agda does not contain all Turing computable functions means little about your ultimate ability to write and execute Turing equivalent programs using Agda.

I think this is now more of a sociology and scientific communication problem than a proof assistants problem.

This has nothing to do with sociology and everything with insufficient knowledge of computability theory. There is no misconception here, dependent type theories that are total and have a computable normalization procedure are Turing-incomplete. This is a theorem (see my answer), not an opinion. Now, what the implication are for practical usability of dependent type theories that are total, that's an entirely different matter.

[Supplemental: I rewrote the answer so that any shred of vagueness is gone, as it was evoking religuous zeal, and I would prefer to stick to math. Everything is explained in terms of a widely accepted and general idea of models of computation, namely (typed) realizability theory. There are of course other ways of modeling computation, and anyone else is welcome to present a coherent mathematically mature alternative picture in their own answer.]
We work with typed partial combinatory algebras as models of computation. These include a host of examples, ranging from Turing machines, Turing machines with oracles, $\lambda$-calculi of various kinds, programming languages, topological models based on Scott domains, topological models based on the Baire space, etc.
My notes on realizability cover all the material needed to understand the following definitions and theorems. I shall refer to theorems and definitions therein.
I shall call typed partial combinatory algebras (tpca)"models of computation". We shall also assume that all tpcas under consideration have numerals (Definition 2.6.3 of the notes.)
Kleene's first algbra $\mathbb{K}_1$ is the untyped pca whose elements are natural numbers and application is defined by $m \bullet n = \phi_m(n)$, where $\phi$ is a standard enumeration of partial computable maps.
Definition 1: A model of computation $\mathbb{A}$ is computable if it can be simulated by Turing machines, i.e., there exists a decidable simulation $\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{K}_1$.
(See Definition 2.8.8 for definition of decidable simulation.)
From definition 1 it follows that any total function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ realized (Definition 2.8.16) in a computable model is Turing computable.
Definition 2: A model of computation $\mathbb{A}$ is Turing-complete if there exists a decidable simulation $\mathbb{K}_1 \to \mathbb{A}$.
(Note: An alternative definition of Turing completeness of a tpca is given in the notes as 2.8.16. I will leave it as an exercise to think about what happens with the alternative definition.)
Martin-Löf type theory (MLTT) is a model of computation $\mathbb{M}$ whose types are the closed types of MLTT, and the elements of a type $T$ are the closed terms of type $T$, quotiented by definitional equality. (This is a standard way of turning a $\lambda$-calculus into a tpca, see John Longley's PhD for variations, such as using open terms.)
We have the following:
Theorem 3: Suppose $\mathbb{A}$ is a computable total typed combinatory algebra, with a decidable simulation $\gamma : \mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{K}_1$, such that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists \mathtt{t} \in |\mathbb{A}_{\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}}| .\, \gamma(\mathtt{t}, n)\}$ is computably enumerable. Then $\mathbb{A}$ it is not Turing complete.
Proof. It may help to think of $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists \mathtt{t} \in |\mathbb{A}_{\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}}| .\, \gamma(\mathtt{t}, n)\}$ as the set of Gödel codes of elements of $\mathbb{A}$ of type $\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}$.
Let $e : \mathbb{N} \to \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists \mathtt{t} \in |\mathbb{A}_{\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}}| .\, \gamma(\mathtt{t}, n)\}$ be a computable enumeration. It suffices to find a Turing-computable total map $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which is not realized by $\mathbb{A}$. Such a map $f$ is obtained by diagonalization against $e$: given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $\mathtt{t} \in |\mathbb{A}_{\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}}|$ such that $e(n) = \mathtt{t}$, and $f$ can compute (using $\gamma$) $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathtt{t}\,\overline{n} + 1 = \overline{k}$. If $f$ were realized by some $\mathtt{f} \in |\mathbb{A}_{\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}}|$, it would follow that $\mathtt{f} \, m = \mathtt{f} \, m + 1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gamma(\mathtt{f}, e(m))$. $\Box$
Corollary 4: MLTT qua typed combinatory algebra $\mathbb{M}$ is not Turing complete.
Proof. Obviously, $\mathbb{M}$ is a total tpca. We may define a decidable simuation $\gamma : \mathbb{M} \to \mathbb{K}_1$ by setting $\gamma(\mathtt{t})$ to be the Gödel code of $\mathtt{t}$. The set featuring in the statement of Theorem 3 is computably enumerable because it is decidable whether a given number $n$ encodes a closed term of type $\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}$ in MLTT. $\Box$
Remark: Corollary 4 applies to many variations of MLTT, such as MLTT with coinductive types, inductive types, etc, so long as it is decidable whether a given number encodes a closed term of type $\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{nat}$.
In type theory we often model computation by a monad, such as the delay monad (or Agda's $\mathtt{IO}$ monad suggested by Guillaume Allais). The basic idea is that the computable partial maps $\mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{N}$ are represented as closed terms of type $\mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{Delay} \; \mathtt{nat}$, where $\mathtt{Delay}$ is a monad defined in an otherwise total type theory.
This sort of approach essentially corresponds to representing partial computable maps via the Kleene normal form theorem. The so-called "fuel" of the delay monad corresponds to Kleene's use the minimization operator in the normal form theorem.
Can we reintrpret a type theory with such a delay monad as a typed partial combinatory algebra? It seems so, although someone would have to check the details. The idea is to define the function type $\mathtt{t} \to \mathtt{u}$ of the corresponding tpca to be the type $\mathtt{t} \mathtt{Delay} \; \mathtt{u}$ of the type theory, and use the monadic bind to set up the tpca application operation. This should give a Turing-complete model of computation.
However, this is not at all useful to gauge the computational power of a type theory, because we can play the exact same trick with System T already (define $\mathtt{Delay} \; \mathtt{t} = \mathtt{nat} \to \mathtt{t}$ and use the input as fuel).

I challenge you to make Definition 2 precise by defining "model of computation" in enough generality that it includes Turing machines, lambda calculi, cellular automata, and other examples you can think of. Without such a definition Theorem 5 is neither provable nor refutable. I'd love to know one such general definition that doesn't have the fault that for any total programming language (MLTT, or even just STLC), there are at least two ways to formalize it as such a "model of computation" such that one is Turing-complete and the other is not.

@Li-yaoXia:  I have rephrased my answer to a purely mathematical one. I invite anyone else who to give an alternative, similarly comprehensive mathematical account if they wish to do so. I am happy to answer further mathematical questiond and give clarifications, but I will not participate in a religuous war. (I also removed comments that were designed to trigger you, apologies for that.)

Is this a typed pca: consider STLC with Nat, a unary type constructor M, with return, bind, and a fix : (M a -> M a) -> M a. A pca type t denotes the STLC type [t], where the denotation is defined by [Nat] = M Nat, [t -> u] = M ([t] -> [u]), [t * u] = M ([t] * [u]). The set A(t) is the set of STLC terms of type [t]. One may object that this is no longer "STLC" because non-termination is possible via fix, or that this encoding of STLC as a pca is somehow not natural. I rather think that formal non-Turing-completeness claims very partially capture expressiveness.

My home-grown definition of model of computation is: a set of programs $P$ and an evaluation function $e : P \to (\mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{N})$. A pair $(P, e)$ is Turing-complete if $e$'s image includes the general recursive functions. It's intentionally broad, useless for theory. "What a language can express" is inherently a fuzzy notion, and that definition leaves room for that fuzziness. There may be more than one way to view a concrete language (e.g., STLC) as such a pair $(P,e)$: Turing-(in)completeness claims can only be made about specific encodings/usages of a language.

Be reassured that I was not offended in any way by your jabs. I make outrageous claims to provoke experts into giving me history lessons.

I am not sure the whether you get a tpca with the M thing. You surely get it if you just postulate fix_A : (A → A) → A for every type A. I'd need to think about it.


Is this perhaps a problem with 'common understanding' regarding what it means to be Turing complete?

Indeed it is: a pop-science understanding of dependent types has led to this myth being deeply ingrained after years of unfettered propagation. Turing completeness is about being able to write and run certain programs but some people insist it's about the types being given to these programs (not the ability to write them) which is silly because the notion predates typed languages...
It is true that MLTT without coinduction mandates that "functions always terminate" like a poster on the dev.to thread you linked says. But with coinduction you can happily write programs that are only required to demonstrably make progress on a regular basis. Waiting for a user-interrupt in the form of a Ctrl-C is a form of making progress and so you can absolutely write a program that will go on forever & attempt to run an arbitrary Turing machine / normalise an untyped lambda term.
It's not a hard problem to decide: the people claiming they're not Turing complete only have their strong belief to back their claims, the people claiming they are Turing complete actually show you programs that are supposedly impossible to write. Here, have an interpreter for the untyped lambda calculus in Agda.

You don't need coinduction. An evaluator can be a state-to-state function.

I've always found this kind of debate utterly sterile. "MLTT is Turing-complete" is basically a rephrasing of Kleene's normal form theorem.

In particular, there is a technical definition of "Turing-complete" in extensions of System T, and by any means MLTT is not Turing-complete by this definition. So, to piss both sides: the people claiming MLTT is not Turing complete are technically right but are completely missing the point, while the people claiming MLTT is Turing complete are provably wrong but actually making an unrelated claim that boils down to "nobody gives rightfully a shit about Turing-completeness as long as your language has primitive recursion".

@Li-yao Xia a stepper is not an evaluator.

My point is that a stepper alone is proof of "Turing expressiveness" (and formal definitions of "Turing-completeness" that don't allow it are wrong). Here's another take: you don't need coinduction; you can use the fuel monad (Nat -> Maybe _) instead of the delay monad.

@Pierre-MariePédrot I think your comments would make a good answer.

I saved PMP from having to write a long diatribe.

Conversely, one might argue that Turing Machines are not an adequate model of computation: indeed there is no such thing as a machine that does not halt or crash or gets switched off, eventually.
